# Counting fields (specifically arrays) in a document

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have my document setup as:

```
Collection
     ------> Document
                 ------> Array 1
                         Array 2
                         Array 3
```

I need to be able to count the number (as an Int) of arrays (or fields) in this document and be able to use it in a SwiftUI ForEach statement.

The problem is, I can't just use a specific number, because arrays are constantly being added and removed.

Comment: Create firebase function trigger `onUpdate`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#function_triggers

Comment: Remember to not create infinite loop where `onUpdate` method will trigger it self.

Comment: I don't fully understand what the problem is. If you loop over the fields in your code, can't you can test if they're an array?

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Could you provide pseudo code of what you would like to achieve?

Comment: I'm just going to format it a bit differently. Hopefully it works better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the arrays are constantly being added and removed, then you have two ways in which you can solve this. The first one would be to loop over the fields inside the document and check if the field is an array or not. Or you can simply increment/decrement a counter each time a new array is added or removed.